# Error in compiling "Sample1.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected Import java.util.Scanner;"

Tags: java

hi we just started out our java class in our school and have been left with a homework to do. I already started it in our school computer and sent a text copy to myself so i can work using my computer (basically its a copy-paste text)

here's my code:

```
Import java.util.Scanner*;
public class Sample1{
        public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("AREA AND PERIMETER CALCULATOR");
        System.out.println("[1]SQUARE");
        System.out.println("[2]RECTANGLE");
        System.out.println("[3]TRIANGLE");
        System.out.println("[4]CIRLE");
        System.out.println("[5]PARALLELOGRAM");

        int input;
        System.out.println("Enter Choice:");
        input=sc.nextInt();

        if (input < 6){
            switch (input){
                case 1: 
                int side;
                int perimeter;
                int area;
                System.out.println("Enter Side: ");
                side=sc.nextInt();
                area= side*side;
                perimeter = 4*side;
                System.out.println("The Area is: "+ area);
                System.out.println("The Perimeter is: "+ perimeter);
                break;

                case 2:
                int length;
                int width;
                //int area;
                //int perimeter;
                System.out.println("Enter width: ");
                width=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter length: ");
                length=sc.nextInt();
                area= length*width;
                perimeter= 2*(length+width);
                System.out.println("The Area is: "+ area);
                System.out.println("The Perimeter is: "+ perimeter);
                break;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

i tried compiling and running it using the cmd but it give me this error it would really help me if you could point out how to fix it to a beginner (i've also noticed that ".Scanner" doesn't change its font color to blue in which it was on my school's computer.

Comment: wrong tag im so sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:-

```
 import java.util.Scanner*;
```

to this:-

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
```

this is the syntax of the import:

```
  import package_name.subpackage_name.class;
```

Comment: i've tried it still no luck. btw im using notepad++ and cmd to edit compile. I've also installed jdk-8u144-windows-x64. do i need to install more programs?

Comment: @YvesAsidillo Also note the lowercase `import`.

Comment: @Izruo ayeee lol that worked. Damn never thought it was that case sensitive. Thanks to both of you

Comment: @YvesAsidillo you only need the jdk and add it to the path in windows. But its easier to just use eclipse if that is possible

Comment: @PeterHaddad i've already set the path to the jdk bin. it was the case sensitivity that causes my problem. Thank you guys you're the best!